# What is Mordell-Weil lattice?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

What is Mordell-Weil lattice?

Comment: It is Mordell-Weil group equipped with Néron-Tate pairing (see Silverman's book for the definition of these objects).

Comment: I have voted to close: FB's comment is the correct answer.  No need for others to get involved.  

Comment: Almost correct: it's the quotient of the MW group by the torsion group, equipped with the Néron-Tate pairing.

Comment: Hm, even that's not quite right for a constant curve with non-torsion points...  So form the quotient by the subgroup of points of height zero (which contains the torsion group).

Answer (score 2):

[T Shioda ：Mordell-Weil lattice][1]

[1]: http://www.rkmath.rikkyo.ac.jp/math/shioda/papers/mwl.pdf   more Basic，you also see the homepage of Chao Li about Elliptic Surfaces and Mordell-Weil Lattices in harvard university。